# How much important CPU and Motherboard are in a gaming perspective?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard

A friend of mine offered me a GTX Titan X, to include in my current setup. (Potential) problem is : my CPU is an Intel Core i5 3570K (@ 3.4GHz), and my motherboard is a MSI ""gaming"" (what's that even supposed to mean) Z77A-G45.

My question is : will the CPU significantly impact my in game performances by dragging down this beautiful video card ? In others words : do i need to buy a new one ? 
When it come to the motherboard, i'm not really concerned, since it has a 3.0 PCI-E 16x slot, it should be fine, just asking to be sure.

Thanks

Comment: Why is top of theine CPU and motherboard is a problem, it's not brand new, but it was top of the line but neither it the Titan x it's already been replaced ( I think) nvidia product lines are hard to track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there will be a huge performance impact, your CPU ist quite okay.

But: it definitely depends on the game and how it profits from a fast CPU, so no promises here.

You should probably have a look at your PSU if it can handle the cards power usage.

Have fun with the card :)

Generally I personally go for the following pririty list (to answer the title of the question)

1. RAM (if its too less and the system has to swap, its no fun at all :/
2. Graphics card (I guess that I dont have to explain that...)
3. CPU (usually after some minimum requirement you can only get little more FPS with a better CPU)

Comment: Yeah, the PSU upgrade is already shipped ! :D
So, do you think that waiting for some month to upgrade the CPU will not be a terrible mistake ? Cause i can't really buy one right now :/

Comment: I'm sure you'll have a lot of fun with your old CPU as well. If you want to get a clear picture, just look at your CPU usage while playing. If your CPU is "bored" all the time, you won't need a new one soon.
I'd rather wait a relatively long time to save money for a really great new CPU (Skylake i7 maybe?), then you have the perfect rig :D

Comment: That's clever, even if I'll have to change my board as well (damn socket can't you Just stay the same ? :( ) 
Thanks for the advice !

Answer (score -2):

The graphics card if better than what you have now, will improve your graphics and allow for better graphics settings in game, along with better frame rates. Your CPU will work as before, though you may have some bottlenecking. All in all, you should notice graphics improvement. You won't be able to use the graphics card to it's fullest potential, but neither will a low end I7 compared to the high end I7. Do make sure that your PSU power supply unit can handle it, usually a 600-watt is fine. Your circumstance will depend on your setup, printers and what have you.